# UISliderCell next to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, positioning, uislider

I'm a beginner in iOS development and I have to put in the same UITableViewCell a label (on the left), a subtitle (on the right) and a slider in the middle.
For now the Label and subtitle are in a cell above the slider.
Is there any way to do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add a screenshot to your question and describe the expected vs. the existing behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes are you using StoryBoards? if so change the cell Style to Custom then drag the other elements into the cell place them were ever you want.

Make sure you set the  cell identifier name

May sure you set the tag value to get to them later in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Example:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"stateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  UILabel *stateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];

  StateProvince *myState = [self.states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  stateLabel.text = myState.label;
  }

Comment: There is a story board but composed of two table view cells (2 sections), nothing more in the story board :-( In fact there is a class SliderCell with a slSliderValueChanged method and here is the code to display the two cells of the first table view :

Comment: case 3:

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SelectedMeetingCell"];

                [cell.textLabel setText:@"Duration"];
                [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[Utilities StringFromDuration:Agenda.InitialDuration.doubleValue]];                    return cell;

Comment: case 4:
                sliderCell = (SliderCell*)[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SliderCell" bundle:nil].view;   
                [sliderCell setDelegate:self];
                [sliderCell.slider setValue:Agenda.InitialDuration.doubleValue];
                return sliderCell;

Comment: Is the UITableViewCell inside a UITableView that's inside a  UITableViewControler?  it needs to be to get the Table view delegate the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" method will not be called unless the it is.